# MixedRealityToolkit Spectator preview example building errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

Running into errors trying to test and build the mixed reality spectator preview example scene. I would like to be able to build inside a folder then run the .sln file to release to the HoloLens. The build errors are shown in the uploaded picture. Any ideas? I have tried on both a windows and mac computer. [ScreenshotOnMacVersion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0FZQ.png)[ScreenshotOnWindowsVersion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCEQY.png)

Comment: Please don't add code and output as pictures. Did you check if you are on the correct target platform, .Net version, is your Unity version supported  etc?

Comment: Yes, in the build settings i have the universal windows platform, target device - HoloLens, build type -  D3D, latest SDK, and latest visual studio version. I am also using Unity 2017.4.20f2 which is the latest updated version to build to the HoloLens device. @derHugo

Comment: @Medlin Is your target platform IL2CPP or .NET scripting backend?  Try switching that to whatever it's not currently set to.

Comment: @slaphshot33324 I have tried switching around the target platform. Currently, I have managed to reduce the build errors. In the Holotoolkit the main errors that is occurring is the holotoolkit-Preview/QRTractor. It states that the type or namespace name 'Preview' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.Perception.Spatial' (Are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Medlin You have visually confirmed that the namespace exists where it needs to be and that Preview is contained in that namespace?

Comment: FYI you can't build for UWP on a mac - it needs Windows.  All hololens dev will have to be on your Windows machine (unless you use a VM etc..) .   There's an issue that matches (what we can see) of the error message https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/3040 here, but I'd suggest checking first that you followed the SpectatorView build instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/spectator-view#building-the-spectator-view-native-plugin carefully as that would have let you know about building on a mac (:

Comment: @Jethro my main focus is building on the windows platform for the hololens. The reason I used a mac was to test if I could build directly for to an iPhone but i received build errors as well. I also have tried following that github link to fix the error but was unable to build. If anyone has successfully built the spectator preview to a project I would really appreciate to see there setup or the steps they personally went through.